# Code Changes in Jenkins are not being displayed in BitBucket repository

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I am having a free-style project in Jenkins. I have configured git in it like this:
[image]

and build triggers as **Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket**. I made a few changes in the code fetched to Jenkins using **Content Replace** plugin. I want to push back these changes to Bitbucket. I am having **Post-build Actions** as follows:
[image]

The changes are not being displayed in the Bitbucket after the successful build. Here are the build logs:

```
    Started by user Muhammad Jamshaid Iqbal
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Ceye-admin
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential 54ad2528-b143-4dc5-978f-ff99de2c28f3
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url http://ip:7990/scm/tes/ceye-admin.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://ip:7990/scm/tes/ceye-admin.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.20.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- http://ip.4:7990/scm/tes/ceye-admin.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 89acfff8ce6d3bd9fb7382143557c84b0d50e9c7 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 89acfff8ce6d3bd9fb7382143557c84b0d50e9c7 # timeout=10
Commit message: "nginx.conf edited online with Bitbucket"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 89acfff8ce6d3bd9fb7382143557c84b0d50e9c7 # timeout=10
content-replace start
 > replace content of file: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Ceye-admin/nginx.conf
   > replace : [            proxy_pass http://ip1:9091/;] => [            proxy_pass http://ip2:9091/;]
   > replace : [            proxy_pass http://ip1:9093/jasperserver/;] => [            proxy_pass http://ip2:9093/jasperserver/;]
   > replace : [            proxy_pass http://ip1:9092/login?next=/;] => [            proxy_pass http://ip2:9092/login?next=/;]
   > replace : [            proxy_pass http://ip1:9092/static;] => [            proxy_pass http://ip2:9092/static;]
   > replace times: 4, [ip1] => [ip2]
content-replace end
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential 54ad2528-b143-4dc5-978f-ff99de2c28f3
Pushing HEAD to branch master at repo origin
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.20.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git push http://git_link:7990/scm/tes/ceye-admin.git HEAD:master # timeout=10
Finished: SUCCESS
```

What I might be doing wrong in here? Everything in Jenkins is working but the change is not appearing in the BitBucket repository.

Comment: I do not see `git add ...` and `git commit ...` after `content-replace`.

Comment: @GeroldBroser how do I do that? Would you please mention it? I am new to jenkins]

Comment: I'd try a shell build step after the Content Replace build step.